# Submit Vee Validate form programatically from a button in another Vue slot

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vee-validate

I have the following Modal containing a simple "Change password" form. The submit button is in the footer of the modal while the form is in the body slot of the Modal. How can I submit the form programmatically when clicking on the Save button in the footer?

Modal code;

```html
<Modal
    v-if="changingPassword"
    title="Change Password"
    @close="() => (changingPassword = false)"
>
    <VForm class="form w-100" @submit="onFormSubmit" :validation-schema="login">
        <Field
            tabindex="2"
            class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid"
            type="password"
            name="password"
        />

        <Field
            tabindex="2"
            class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid"
            type="password"
            name="new-password"
            autocomplete="new-password"
        />

        <Field
            tabindex="2"
            class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-solid"
            type="password"
            name="confirm-password"
            autocomplete="off"
        />
    </VForm>
    <template #footer>
        <button @click="submitForm">Save</button>
    </template>
</Modal>
```

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
function submitForm(e) {
     //Submit form here
}
</script>
```

Comment: how did you finally go about achieving this? I am stuck at the same querstion.

Comment: I used Element Plus instead